# How can I convert a single Character type to uppercase?

Tags: swift

All I want to do is convert a single `Character` to uppercase without the overhead of converting to a `String` and then calling `.uppercased()`. Is there any built-in way to do this, or a way for me to call the `toupper()` function from C without any bridging? I really don't think I should have to go out of my way for something so simple.

Comment: I think you have to go via String. Also the uppercase version of a single character can be a string with multiple characters, e.g. "ß" -> "SS".

Comment: Also `toupper()` operates only on `char` and is locale dependent.

Comment: Another example: "ﬃ" (ligature) ->  "FFI". Or "ᾀ" (some greek letter) -> "ἈΙ"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To call the C `toupper()` you need to get the Unicode code point of the `Character`. But `Character` has no method for getting its code point (a `Character` may consist of multiple code points), so you have to convert the `Character` into a `String` to obtain any of its code points.

So you really have to convert to `String` to get anywhere. Unless you store the character as a [`UnicodeScalar`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unicodescalar) instead of a `Character`. In this case you can do this:

```
assert(unicodeScalar.isASCII) // toupper argument must be "representable as an unsigned char"
let uppercase = UnicodeScalar(toupper(CInt(unicodeScalar.value)))
```

But this isn't really more readable than simply using `String`:

```
let uppercase = Character(String(character).uppercased())
```

Comment: Note that the last line can crash at runtime, e.g. for `character = "ß"` (these crazy Germans :)

Answer (score 0):

just add this to your program

```
extension Character {
    
    //converts a character to uppercase
    func convertToUpperCase() -> Character {
        if(self.isUppercase){
            return self
        }
        return Character(self.uppercased())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `.uppercased()` method for `Character` was added in Swift since this question was asked, so there's no need to worry about converting it to a `String` or using C bridging any more.